# Which kind of grammar is the following?

Tags: grammars

Let me define the following "grammar":

$$A_0 \leftarrow 1$$

$$A_{i+1} \leftarrow A_i \mid A_i \  K_{i+1} \mid A_i \ K_{i+1} \ A_i$$

where $1$ and $K_i$ are terminals (infinite amount of them: $K_1, K_2, \dots$ ), $A_0, A_1, \dots$ are non-terminals, $\mid$ means alternative, $\leftarrow$ defines a non-terminal, $i$ is an integer such that $i \geq 0$.

That is, it looks like a grammar composed of an infinite number of rules and terminals.

My questions are:

1. can I call such a construction a "grammar"?
2. in which grammar category can I include it?
3. have such structures been studied before, can anyone give links or bibliographic references?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, if someone downvotes, it is welcome a comment to allow improve the question or to withdraw it in case there are something completly incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted, maybe someone found the notation confusing. I tried to latexify it, and make it a bit clearer, hopefully the changed version will show up soon.

Comment: @Laszlo Kozma: Thanks a lot for the edits. I didn't know I could use $$ in my text.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer would be that, having an infinite set of rules, this is not a grammar in the usual sense. Languages over infinite alphabets have been investigated, but usually using register automata rather than grammars.

That being said, you could treat the language as a limit (i.e. infinite union) of finitary languages defined by the "truncations" $G_i$ which you obtain by omitting all indices greater than $i$. I am unfortunately not familiar with research into such beasts.